# The set of complete vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-algebras

The set of all complete vector fields in $\mathbb R^{n}$ is closed under Lie bracket? is this set a $D$-module where $D$ is the ring of bounded smooth funcions? Can anyone recomend me a book on the subject?
Thanks!

Clarification: Im interested on and aplication of this things. What I need actually is to create diffeomorphisms by combining linear transformations $A_{i}$
acting locally. So I combine some linear vector fields wich flows at t=1 are the original linear transformations, (i.e. the fields as linear trasformation are the matrix logaritms of $A_{i}$) with gaussian funtions as weights and then integrate the resulting ODE up to t=1. So I was wondering if there was a more general framework to express this things.. some kind of infinite dimentional Lie theory, where the part of integrating the ODE up to t=1 (finding the flow of the resulting vector field at t=1) can be seen as a kind of Lie exponential of the field. Im more interested on finding a good languaje then in the question itself

Comment: Please show you've tried to answer the question and where you've got stuck.

Comment: Im interested on and aplication of this things. What I need actually is to create diffeomorphisms by combining linear transformations acting locally. So I combine some linear vector fields with gaussian funtions as weights and then integrate the ODE up to t=1. So I was wondering if there was a more general framework to express this things.. some kind of infinite dimentional Lie theory. Im more interested on finding a good languaje then in the question itself.

Comment: Okay, I think it would be a good idea to try to add that information into the question, so it's clear why you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

The set of closed vector fields is not closed under Lie brackets. Neither is it an $\mathbb R$-vector space. Consider the vector fields $$\sin(x^2 y)\, \partial_x,\; \partial_y, \; x^2\sin^2(x)\, \partial_x, \; x^2\cos^2(x)\, \partial_x$$ on $\mathbb R^2$. All of them are complete. The first two because they are bounded, the other two because they point in the $x$-direction and vanish periodically in this direction (so no blow up is possible).

Note that $[ \partial_y, \sin(x^2y)\partial_x] = x^2 \cos(x^2 y)\partial_x$ and $x^2\sin^2(x)\, \partial_x +  x^2\cos^2(x)\, \partial_x = x^2\, \partial_x$. Both of these vector fields point in the $x$-direction and along the $x$-axis they are equalt to $x^2\, \partial_x$. But $x^2\, \partial_x$ is not complete.